# Retrieving total count of matching rows along with the rows themselves using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I have a PDO snippet that retrieves a bunch of rows from a MySQL table and assigns the field values (2 fields are returned per row) to two arrays like so:

```
$connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,'dbcontext', PROJDBUSER, PROJDBPWD);
$sql= "SELECT contextleft, contextright FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word LIMIT 0, 25";
$xleft = array();
$xright = array();
$countrows = 0;
$word = "[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]";
$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(":word", $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if($query->execute()) {
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $pattern = '/\b'. $term .'\b/ui';
        $replacer = function($matches) { return '<span class="highlight">' . $matches[0] . '</span>'; };
        $xleft[$countrows] = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replacer, $row['contextleft']);
        $xright[$countrows] = $row['contextright'];
        $countrows++;
    }
    $notfound = null;
}
$connect = null;
```

This works perfect. As you can see, I use the **LIMIT** clause to ensure only a maximum of 25 rows are extracted. However, there can actually be many more matching records in the table and I need to also retrieve the total count of **all** matching records along with the returned rows. The end goal is pagination, something like: *25 of 100 entries returned...*

I understand I have 2 options here, both involving 2 queries instead of a single one:

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word;
SELECT contextleft, contextright FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word LIMIT 0, 25";
```

or...

```
$sql= "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contextleft, contextright FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word LIMIT 0, 25;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();";
```

But I am still confused around retrieving the returned count value in PHP. Like I could access the fields by running the `fetchAll()` method on the query and referencing the field name. How can I access the count value returned by either `FOUND_ROWS()` or `COUNT()`? Also, is there any way to use a single SQL statement to get both count as well as the rows?

Comment: Use [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate query with the count, then you can retrieve its value exactly the same way as you read the values from any queries, there is no difference.

If you use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, then you need to have a separate query to call [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Since this is again a normal query, you can read its output the same way as you do now.

You can technically retrieve the record count within the query itself by adding a count(*) field to the query:

```
SELECT contextleft, contextright, (select count(*) from tblcontext) as totalrecords FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word LIMIT 0, 25
```

or

```
SELECT contextleft, contextright, totalrecords
FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft, (select count(*) as totalrecords from tblcontext) t REGEXP :word LIMIT 0, 25
```

Limit affects the number of records returned, but does not affect the number of rows counted by the count() function. The only drawback is that the count value will be there in every row, but in case of 25 rows, that may be an acceptable burden.

You need to test which method works the best for you.

Comment: I think I like the second idea better since it keeps everything in the same query. However, I am just curious as to whether it will have any performance impact. Will MySQL actually perform the count operation every time it hits a matching record or does it do the counting only once and then just appends the value with every row returned?

Comment: +1 for this reassurance: "Limit affects the number of records returned, but does not affect the number of rows counted by the count() function."

Comment: You need to test, which of the 3 method works the best for you.

Comment: Somehow, the `count(*)` idea is breaking my code. Without it, the query returns 25 records (I know there's a total of at least 200) as expected but with `count(*)` added, it only returns one.

Comment: Ahh, now I see. Just as I suspected, looks like it's gonna perform the count operation with every single match which means it would count the total number of matching records 25 times on a single query! :(